# how to keep padding zeros infront of number values whenconverting a dataframe 'to_csv'?

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe and wish to pad numbers with one zero infront which the code below achieves. However, when I convert this dataframe to a csv, it returns the column WITHOUT the padded zeros? I've read that you must convert thhe column to a string datatype which i have but the  problem remains, why??

```
A_df['paon'] = A_df['paon'].str.zfill(4)
A_df['paon'] = A_df['paon'].astype(str)

A_df.to_csv('C:/Users/Sam/Downloads/Housr.csv')
```

Comment: Are you using excel to open the csv file? Try to open it on notepad for example and see if the leading zeros are there

Comment: The zeros are present in notepad, but obviously need the dataframe in excel

Comment: You can look at this link for example to see how to deal with this problem in excel https://www.iqaccountingsolutions.com/blog/dealing-with-leading-zeros-when-opening-a-csv-file-in-excel/

Comment: convert the column properties to text in excel

Comment: @Shijith Won't help to get back the padding zeros after excel already opened and read that as a number. *fmarm* pointed to the solution, as this is not a python issue, but an excel one.